# phoca gallery facebook connetion error

Tags: facebook

I am trying to use the Phoca gallery facebook option to import facebook photo album into my joomla website.

I created the facebook App and got the App ID and App secret.While creating the Phoca gallery new facebook user using this App id and Secret when clicking on "Login- connect to Facebook" button I am getting the following error message:

Invalid Scopes: offline_access, publish_stream, photo_upload. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/fa ... ermissions.

phoca gallery 3.2.7 with joomla 2.5.28

Any idea about what this error is and how to solve it ?

Comment: The plugin you are using is asking for permissions that do not exist any more. Either as the provider of the plugin to fix it, or go look at the source code to see where it asks for permissions and fix it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

always use the latest version. For now, it is Phoca Gallery version 4.2.2 and Joomla! version 3.4.8: http://www.phoca.cz/download/category/1-phoca-gallery-component

As Facebook changes API often, the permissions and other parameters need to be updated too. Update to the latest version should solve this problem.